# How to enable zooming on product page?

Tags: magento2, zoom

I installed Magento's latest version on the XAMPP server. But, I'd like to add zoom for product images the same as Magento 1.

How to enable zooming on the product page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create custom theme and add below code to your `view.xml` file.

**Code to enable magnifier:**

```
   <var name="magnifier">
        <var name="fullscreenzoom">20</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
        <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
        <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
        <var name="width"></var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
        <var name="height"></var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
        <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
        <var name="enabled">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
        <var name="mode">outside</var> <!-- Zoom type (outside/inside) -->
    </var>
```

Check [here](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-custom-theme-magento-2-part-1/) if you have no idea regarding how to create custom theme.

Comment: Its not working for me

Comment: What's problem ? You've custom theme or what ?

Comment: Yes i am using porto theme, i used path /app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/etc/view.xml

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom theme and put view.xml under `app/design/frontend/Vendorname/Themename/etc`

Copy that file form magento installation/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml

In that file you can find following code

```
<var name="magnifier">
            <var name="fullscreenzoom">20</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
            <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
            <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
            <var name="width"></var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
            <var name="height"></var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
            <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
            <var name="enabled">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
        </var>
```

Make this  `<var name="enabled">false</var>` true so it should be

```
<var name="enabled">true</var>
```